# Linux volume control message standard

Tags: sound, volume-control, dbus, xfce-panel

My audio control in top panel on Ubuntu Studio 1704 is broken.

[image]

On the top is the audio control from `Settings Manager -> Panel -> Items` labelled as `Audio Mixer`. I don't know what the providing app is, but its configuration looks like this:

[image]

No matter how I drag the slider, nothings changes. Black field with volume icon underneath it is notification that appears when I pressed volume down button. I don't know yet what program is showing this notification and what program is sending the message that volume had changed. But it appears that top panel control doesn't get the message.

I assume that volume control messages are sent through DBUS (correct me if I wrong, because I have no references), so either top panel doesn't listen, or it listens for the wrong message.

Is there a standard for volume up event message in Linux DBUS and where it is documented?

When I press volume down, `dbus-monitor` reports these event series:

```
method call time=1492408712.461795 sender=:1.30 -> destination=:1.43 serial=50 path=/org/freedesktop/Notifications; interface=org.freedesktop.Notifications; member=Notify
   string "Xfce volume daemon"
   uint32 0
   string "audio-volume-low"
   string "Volume is at -1%"
   string ""
   array [
   ]
   array [
      dict entry(
         string "value"
         variant             int32 -1
      )
   ]
   int32 -1
method call time=1492408712.473077 sender=:1.43 -> destination=org.gnome.ScreenSaver serial=90 path=/org/gnome/ScreenSaver; interface=org.gnome.ScreenSaver; member=GetActive
method return time=1492408712.473326 sender=:1.86 -> destination=:1.43 serial=20 reply_serial=90
   boolean false
method call time=1492408712.474693 sender=:1.43 -> destination=org.gnome.SessionManager serial=91 path=/org/gnome/SessionManager; interface=org.gnome.SessionManager; member=IsInhibited
   uint32 8
error time=1492408712.474727 sender=org.freedesktop.DBus -> destination=:1.43 error_name=org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown reply_serial=91
   string "The name org.gnome.SessionManager was not provided by any .service files"
method return time=1492408712.519448 sender=:1.43 -> destination=:1.30 serial=92 reply_serial=50
   uint32 10
```

But I guess something is wrong/missing here.

---

**UPDATE**: Now with `alsa-mixer`. I don't know why should I care about it, so your comments are welcome. Note that while ALSA master volume is at 50%, the black indicator is still low and the message on DBus says "Volume is at 1%".

[image]

To get my volume back at 100%, I had to raise `alsa-mixer` levels for `Master`, `PCM` (what is this?) and `Front` bars to maximum.

Answer (score 0):

You probably know this but....Have you tried accessing Alsamixer via the terminal?
At least you can check on the position of the volume sliders and see if a conflict has killed one off.

```
cntl+alt+t
alsamixer
```

Comment: Updated with more info.

Comment: PCM: 'regular' audio (sound files, videos, etc.) is processed through this line. This should never be muted (unless you don't want to head audio). Unless things are very quiet you should also take care to keep this at a gain level of no more than 0dB (on this line, alsamixer represents amplification in red, so about 3/4 volume represents the highest unamplified level). See http://computing.help.inf.ed.ac.uk/alsa-mixer I hope this helped - I had this issue one after plugging in a headphone jack and removing it when switched off.